# How do I fit an exact number of ListView items on screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I would like the rows in a ListView to be sized so that exactly six of them can fit on the screen. For that, I would need to know how much vertical space is available to the ListView (not the whole screen). However, no measuring can be done in onCreate() since no views have been rendered yet.

If I make measurements after rendering, the ListView might be drawn and then resized, which may be distracting. What is the smartest way to establish the necessary row height before rendering the ListView?

Answer (score 4):

in `onCreate` you can get the height of your screen and divide by 6.
Now in your `getView` you get the reference of the top layout for each item, suppost you have named it's id to root and i.e it's a `LinearLayout`.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if(view == null){ some inflate }

    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root);
    LayoutParams lp = root.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = screenHeight/6;
    root.setLayoutParams(lp);

    ....

    return view;
}
```

Yes, this assumes the `ListView` is in fullscreen.
If you have other layouts, you will have to get those height into account.

Then your height will be: `int heightForEachItem = (screenHeight - otherlayoutsHeightTogether) / 6;`

Comment: this is assuming the listview is full screen and there is no actionbar present or possibly even soft navigation buttons though

Comment: yes, that is true. I added a comment below the code.

Comment: Nah, there is an ActionBar and everything. I didn't know that one could measure LayoutParams though, that was new.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the earliest you can measure a ListView is in the `onGlobalLayout()` callback.
Here is my example.

```
params = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(-1,-1);
listview.getViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout(){ //this is called just before rendering
        params.height = listview.getHeight()/6; // this is what I was looking for
        listview.getViewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); // this is called very often
    }
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<...>(int position, ...){
    @Override
    public View getView(...){
        LinearLayout item = new LinearLayout(context);
        item.setLayoutParams(params);
        // add text, images etc with getItem(position) and item.addView(View)
        return item;
    }
}
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```